# mod_rewrite and iframe problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using .htaccess to create a directory based website with pretty links, ie. www.website.com/home, website.com/portfolio.

On one of the pages I have an iframe, and the .htaccess is overriding the iframe src.

Is it possible to tell .htaccess to not rewrite iframe sources?

Answer (score 1):

No, mod_rewrite rewrite rules affect all HTTP requests. Apache doesn't know the request originated from an iframe. Either use a URL for the iframe that doesn't match one of your rewrite rules, or alter the rewrite rule to not match the URL you don't want rewritten.

Comment: Thanks Dan - the problem was that the page (directory) being viewed was rewritten as the directory does not actually exist - and it was forcing the iframe as well as it was also part of the redirected page.

However it looks like overflow: scroll produces the right effect I am looking for.

Comment: You mean the iframe's source was a relative URL, which is now relative to a nonexistant directory? You have to deal with that (use an absolute URL, or a URL relative to the root), there's nothing the web server can automatically do about it.